# Firefox remote debugging with websockets

Tags: selenium, firefox, web-scraping, websocket

I found [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/12/using-headless-mode-in-firefox/) and now I wonder if it possible to control Firefox in the headless mode via websocket?

Actually, I am interested in this command:

`/path/to/firefox --start-debugger-server ws:6000 -headless`

So, how should I use it and what commands should be sent via websocket connection? Does it mean that I can establish just websocket connection with  running Firefox in headless mode on the server and send some commends (i.e. to open pages or evaluate javascript on the page or get some DOM elements)?

Is there some API to control browser in headless mode directly w/o any web-driver (Selenium e.t.c.)?

Unfortunately, there is not enough documentation on the Internet about this. Thanks!

Comment: did you find something regarding this ?

I also found that it seems it should work based on 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1286281 and 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119894

I am able to start firefox properly, websocket port is open(6000, default one) ... but no clue on how to proceed